# Getting error before install an apk programatically Android 8.1

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

I've read a lot of similar problems like mine here, but nothing solves my problem.

I'm trying to install an APK programmatically. The apk is located at Download Folder. Its name is Hello.apk.

Here my Java Class:

```
private void instala_apk() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);

        Uri provider = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                this,
                getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider",
                new File(path));

        intent.setDataAndType(provider,
                "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);


        startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
    }
```

My Manisfest:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.myapplication">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <provider
            android:name=".GenericFileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/filepaths"
                tools:replace="android:resource"/>
        </provider>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="hello.apk"
        path="Download"

        />
</paths>
```

But when i run my app i don't have any error. Just received a message
"There Was A Problem Parsing the Package".
What am i doing wrong? Am i missing something?

Comment: is package name defined in manifest file ?

Comment: Now u can see my full manifest file. Anything wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Nope, everything is fine I guess

Comment: Chances are that the app is still in your phone